# OS X Yosemite version is a weird number

Tags: macos

A friend of mine has something weird going on on his Mac. When he's in the overview tab in the "About this Mac" section his version of OS X is displayed in a weird form - with numbers. The screenshot will explain more:

[image]

How do I restore the proper name of the OS X?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that your friend's installation appears to be in Dutch, so I suspect that this is a localization / language issue. If you search the web a bit for "yosemite 135122" you will find others with non-English OSX installations reporting the same issue. It seems like this particular string was not properly "translated" into other languages. So other than a strange "About This Mac" screen, this should not cause any issues.

10.10.3 is out already; maybe upgrading will fix it?